# Show content on external website, only if user is a 'fan' of the URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, external

Similar to the ever-trendy Fan Page trick that allows page owners to only show certain content when a user performs the 'like' action (visible-to-connection), I wish to be able to only show certain content on a website once a user has liked the website.

If there is no FB code for this, I have considered using a Facebook like callback (triggered when a user likes on the current page) to set a cookie that establishes a user has liked the page or perhaps a database table that sets a users status to 'liked', again using the callback within the documentation.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen a "fangate" implementation for non-Facebook pages that didn't require you to go through the full Facebook authentication process (with the `user_likes` scope) first. You could set a cookie when they like, but that'll only work if they liked it via your site (i.e. if they liked you on Facebook, it wouldn't get caught by your site), and the cookie could get deleted or lost.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Javascipt SDK to easily accomplish this.

1. First, call FB.init:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/
2. Then call getLoginStatus: 
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
3. If they're not logged in ( not authorized your app ), then call
   FB.login and then recall getLoginStatus.
4. If logged in, then get the user's likes via FQL:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.query/

Comment: That requires an app and authentication, which doesn't sound like what he's looking for.

Comment: "Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks." :)